# What is Cascade Detach within Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, cascade

All in the title :)

I like to understand what is the Cascade Detach thing? I can understand what is a Cascade Remove or something.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

It's all about associations.

Lets say you have two classes `Parent` and `Child` with `OneToMany` association between them. Cascading operation mean that if you are detaching/removing object at the owning side of the association, objects on inverse side are also detached/removed.

Note that this has nothing to do with SQL `On delete/update cascade`, this applies only to PHP data model. But, of course, when it comes to flushing changes, entities that were removed from data model with cascade operations are removed from DB just as well as manually removed entities.